# Double loop to fill dataframe - how to fix "invalid function in complex assignment"

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe:

```
results 2 (612 obs. 281 variables)
ID Q1000_p2000_2016 Q1893_p2039_2016 .... Q1000_p2000_2017 Q1893_p2039_2017
1      392               381                    422              351
2      432               293                    398              310
.       .                 .                      .                .
.       .                 .                      .                .
```

where there are 140 questions from 2016 and 140 from 2017, each year the questions share the same name but each variable name has `"_2016"` or `"_2017"` at the end to discriminate between time periods.

and another dataframe:

```
absdiff (0 obs. 141 variables)
ID Q1000_p2000 Q1893_p2039 ....
```

I want to assign a value in absdiff by taking the absolute difference of the two years, for each question for each `ID`.

In my condition, I check the question number for 2016 (or the first few characters of the variable name) matches the question number for 2017 in results2.

If that holds, I want to assign the absolute difference of the two answers to the corresponding variable/question number in absdiff

I have used

```
for (q in 2:141){
  if (substr(colnames(results2[q]),1,12) == substr(colnames(results2[q+140]),1,12)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(results2)){absdiff$substr(colnames(results2[q]),1,11) <- abs(results2[j,q] - results2[j,(q+140)])}
  }
  else 
    print("ERROR")
}
```

but I get this error message:

> Error in absdiff$substr(colnames(results2[q]), 1, 11) <- abs(results2[j,  : 
>   invalid function in complex assignment

What problem causes this error message? How do I fix it?

For replication sake this can all be simplified to:

```
ID <- c(1,2)
Q1000_p2000_2016 <- c(392,432)
Q1893_p2039_2016 <- c(381,293)
Q1000_p2000_2017 <- c(422,398)
Q1893_p2039_2017 <- c(351,310)    

results2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, Q1000_p2000_2016, Q1893_p2039_2016 ,Q1000_p2000_2017, Q1893_p2039_2017 ))

absdiff <- results2[FALSE,1:3]

    for (q in 2:3){
  if (substr(colnames(results2[q]),1,12) == substr(colnames(results2[q+2]),1,12)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(results2)){absdiff$substr(colnames(results2[q]),1,11) <- abs(results2[j,q] - results2[j,(q+2)])}
  }
  else 
    print("ERROR")
}
```

Comment: You really should read the paper "Tidy Data" by Hadley Wickham (google it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use loops, but just vectorize. Get the 2016 columns, the 2017 columns and then subtract:

```
col2016<-grep("_2016$",names(results2),value=TRUE)
col2017<-grep("_2017$",names(results2),value=TRUE)
absdiff<-results2[,col2017]-results2[,col2016]
#  Q1000_p2000_2017 Q1893_p2039_2017
#1               30              -30
#2              -34               17
```

To retain the `ID` column, just add it after:

```
absdiff$ID<-results2$ID
```

Comment: Is there a way to retain the `ID` variable with this method?

Answer (score 2):

Quick notes on your code for future coding: The cause of the error here is this: `absdiff$substr(colnames(results2[q]),1,11)` because you can't use the dollar sign with a function just because it returns a string, you can however use the slicing brackets like this `absdiff[substr(colnames(results2[q]),1,11)]`.

Another problem with the code is the fact that `absdiff` is initially empty when you call `results2[FALSE,1:3]` you get the column names but not the rows (if you want all the rows remove `FALSE`), which means you won't be able to give values to the new column.

And finally if you think you might need to do these kind of things more in the future I would recommend that you take a look at [Tidy Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data) and the different methods you can use to reshape the data to make analysis easier and more intuitive, as an example with your sample data you could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
new_resutls  <- results2 %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars='ID') %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(question = substr(variable, 1, 11), 
                year = substr(variable, 13, 16))
new_resutls

#   ID         variable value    question year
# 1  1 Q1000_p2000_2016   392 Q1000_p2000 2016
# 2  2 Q1000_p2000_2016   432 Q1000_p2000 2016
# 3  1 Q1893_p2039_2016   381 Q1893_p2039 2016
# 4  2 Q1893_p2039_2016   293 Q1893_p2039 2016
# 5  1 Q1000_p2000_2017   422 Q1000_p2000 2017
# 6  2 Q1000_p2000_2017   398 Q1000_p2000 2017
# 7  1 Q1893_p2039_2017   351 Q1893_p2039 2017
# 8  2 Q1893_p2039_2017   310 Q1893_p2039 2017
```

Your problem can then be solved like this:

```
new_resutls %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID, question) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(absdiff = abs(sum(value*c(1, -1))))

#      ID question    absdiff
#   <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
# 1     1 Q1000_p2000      30
# 2     1 Q1893_p2039      30
# 3     2 Q1000_p2000      34
# 4     2 Q1893_p2039      17
```